# why does the default round function in python fix double rounding errors?

Tags: python, double, rounding, rounding-error

There's something wrong with my understanding of either the round function in python or how doubles are represented in python. I find a very perplexing behavior when rounding numbers that have a double precision rounding error; for example 1.01046+.00002=1.0104799999999998. When I round this to 5 digits, python reports the result as 1.01048, the expected result. But I thought the whole issue was that 1.01046+.00002=1.0104799999999998 because there's no double value that exactly equals 1.01048. If round takes in a double and returns a double, how can it return 1.01048 if no such double exists?

The following code:
`print([1.01046+.00002*i for i in range(6)])`

outputs:
`[1.01046, 1.0104799999999998, 1.0105, 1.0105199999999999, 1.01054, 1.01056]`

wheras this code:
`print([round(1.01046+.00002*i,5) for i in range(6)])`

outputs:
`[1.01046, 1.01048, 1.0105, 1.01052, 1.01054, 1.01056]`

why is it that python doesn't have an exact value for 1.01046+.00002*1, python says "I don't have any such number; I can give you a number that's really close though", but when I ask python to round the resulting number, it goes "oh yeah of course that's 1.01048"

Answer (score 3):

The bit you're missing is that `str(float)` and `repr(float)` return the shortest string that reproduces the original value when passed to `float()`.

So, e.g., despite that there is no representable float exactly equal to one tenth,

```py
>>> 0.1
0.1
```

Doesn't mean it *is* one tenth (and it isn't!), but that `float("0.1")` will return the original value denoted by the literal `"0.1"`, but no shorter string will.

In your example,

```py
>>> import math
>>> 1.01046 + .00002
1.0104799999999998 # shortest string that converts back exactly
```

But there's a different float closer to a multiple of (the mathematical) 1e-5, which is what passing 5 as the second argument to `round()` is asking for. It happens to be exactly 1 unit in the last place larger than the float we computed above:

```
>>> math.nextafter(_, math.inf) # one ULP larger
1.01048
```

But again, that's *not* 1.01048 exactly, but the shortest string that coverts back to the true value:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(_)
Decimal('1.0104800000000000448352466264623217284679412841796875')
```

So the true value returned by `round()` is a smidgen larger than 1.01048.

### Under the covers

`round()` is not a simple function. [In CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bfc57d43d8766120ba0c8f3f6d7b2ac681a81d8a/Objects/floatobject.c#L941), it works hard to deliver the best possible result. This *can* require arbitrary precision arithmetic, to do correctly rounded binary <-> decimal conversions.

In your case, the result of `1.01046 + .00002` is first converted to a correctly rounded decimal string with 5 digits after the decimal point (not a Python-level string, but a C-level buffer of characters). That string is `"1.01048"`. Then that string is converted back to a correctly rounded binary float.

Note that it's no accident that the result *displays* as 1.01048 too: since it came *from* converting the string "1.01048" to a float, and `str/repr()` return the shortest string that reproduces their input, `str/repr()` cannot return a string longer than "1.01048".

But, as already shown, the actual float value is actually a bit larger than that.

Comment: Note: I added info in a new section at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The result of rounding isn't exact, either. But when numbers are printed, there's a default number of significant digits, and it's close enough that it gets printed without any trailing errors.

You can see this if you force the output to 20 digits after the decimal point.

```
>>> for i in range(6):
...     val = 1.01046+.00002*i
...     print(val, round(val, 5), f'{val:.20f} {round(val, 5):.20f}')
... 
1.01046 1.01046 1.01045999999999991381 1.01045999999999991381
1.0104799999999998 1.01048 1.01047999999999982279 1.01048000000000004484
1.0105 1.0105 1.01049999999999995381 1.01049999999999995381
1.0105199999999999 1.01052 1.01051999999999986279 1.01052000000000008484
1.01054 1.01054 1.01053999999999999382 1.01053999999999999382
1.01056 1.01056 1.01055999999999990280 1.01055999999999990280
```

In the cases where `val` and `round(val, 5)` are different, the difference is after the 16th digit after the decimal point, and that's not shown by default.